# LINQ, Select where Title Matches, Else if Object is Null

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a basic tag searching system setup, each tag has a field for an ID for a category. Some tags will have no category.

So in my methods, I just pass a string through to define the category to get in a list.

```
public IQueryable<Tag> List(string category)
{
 //...
}
```

I want to return tags that have no category if nothing is passed through. This works if I write the query like this...

```
return t from db.Tags
       where t.Category == null
       select t;
```

However then I need two queries (one if it is null, one if it is not)
I was wondering if I can do this all in one query for simplification.

The current query is ...

```
return t from db.Tags
       where t.Category.Name == name
       select t;
```

Comment: if `name` is null there, it will just work? Why do you need the `== null` query?

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I have tried it that way. If name is null, it isn't the same thing as equating the object to null - instead it tries to get the Name of the object itself, which is a null object, and throws an error.

Comment: What kind of error/exception? Just to get an idea what might be wrong, because that should just work..

Comment: oh I see what you're doing now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.Tags
.Where(t=> Category==null?t.Category==null:t.Category.Name==Category);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way:

```
if(name == null)
    return t from db.Tags
           where t.Category.Name == null
           select t;
else
    return t from db.Tags
           where t.Category != null && t.Category.Name == name
           select t;
```

You don't want execute a more complicated query on the DB server then needed. If you combine the 2, which is probably possible, the query will also contain an ISNULL check for name.